# Trouble installing mermaid command line interface

Tags: windows, powershell, yarnpkg, mermaid

I'm trying to use the mermaid tool to build diagrams. I installed on windows using,

`yarn add mermaid`

after first downloading scoop and yarn.

And then, to get the command line interface I used,

`yarn add mermaid.cli`

`./node_modules/.bin/mmdc -h`

https://github.com/mermaidjs/mermaid.cli

When I actually try to run the command line options, specifically to generate a diagram I get this error,

```
mmdc : The term 'mmdc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ mmdc -i example2.mmd -o exampleout.png
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mmdc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I installed scoop, yarn, mermaid, and the interface in my user/lastname file since i'm using a work computer, so that might be the issue.

Comment: That kind of error usually means the commands you are running are not in the Path.

Comment: Unless i've been adding it wrong, I have tried to update the path settings to no avail. I did find a solution, and that was to simply install visual studio code, the powershell extension, as well as various mermaid extensions [which I don't think were needed]. I ran the same command in the VS powershell that I tried running before, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: FYI, Path updates to the system do not affect the current console.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Not much more than what I already said. If you update the Path a separate process (e.g., an installer, the GUI, etc.) in Windows, currently open consoles will not see the new Path setting. You will need to close and open them again.

Comment: The more you know.....that worked. I should've known to turn it off and on again. Thank you